# Using Mongo Stitch with Firebase Storage?

Tags: mongodb, firebase, firebase-storage, mongodb-stitch

I'm currently developing a solution that lets users create a parent listing whereby they can upload files, assign child listings to that and then search their listings based on data from both the parent and child listings.

As an example, think of it as an inventory database. You create your parent listing for say a product, give it a name and upload some images of it.  You then create your child listings which would be the stores that stock your product.

Your search capabilities would allow the user to search the product by free text, but also using parameters from the child listings, for example Price, In Stock, Tags etc.

I've tried to develop a concept using Firebase for this which utilises Auth, Storage and Functions, however due to the search limitations of Firestore, it cannot be done.

MongoDB offers something similar to Firebase' functionality whereby I can use Atlas which gives me all the search capabilities I need using Mongo instead of Firestore.  In addition, they also have Stitch which provides the Cloud Function, Trigger and Auth functionality I need.
What they don't offer however is any Storage solution.

Does anyone know a way I can use MongoDB Stitch Auth, alongside Firebase Storage to **integrate directly with the UI** using the Firebase Storage security rules? 
I know I could create a Stitch Function that handles the passing of file from UI to Firebase, however I'd prefer to go direct if possible.

Comment: There is GridFS on Atlas. It's not as powerful as Firebase Storage yet can be used in some scenarios.

Comment: The reason I wanted to use Firebase Storage is I need to use ImageMagick to perform actions on image files that are uploaded.  I've already done the functions in Firebase CF using triggers so it's simple and scalable.
Utilising something like GridFS would mean having to implement manual image processing and queue management etc